# Window wont open from context menu command

Tags: c#, wpf

I got this piece of code for context menu in datagrid:

```
  <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu >
              <MenuItem Header="Detail" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenTruckDetailCmd, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                          <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/MES.WPF.MainLibrary;Component/Resources/ElegantIcons/icon_document_alt.png" Height="20"/>
                          </MenuItem.Icon>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem Header="Časová osa" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenTimeWindowDetailCmd,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                          <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/MES.WPF.MainLibrary;Component/Resources/ElegantIcons/icon_clock.png"  Height="20"/>
                          </MenuItem.Icon>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem Header="Přestávka" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenBreakWindowCmd,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                          <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/MES.WPF.MainLibrary;Component/Resources/ElegantIcons/icon_calendar.png"  Height="20"/>
                          </MenuItem.Icon>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem Header="Foto z vážení"  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenImageGalleryCmd,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                          <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/MES.WPF.MainLibrary;Component/Resources/ElegantIcons/icon_calendar.png"  Height="20"/>
                          </MenuItem.Icon>
              </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
  </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Problem is .. When i click with right mouse button on some menu item, any window i click won´t open.
Any ideas how to deal with it?Thanks.

Comment: May be because Command work after left mouse button click?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: "Problem is .. When i click with right mouse button on some menu item"

Comment: There must be left, not right. Im sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I solved my problem. I removed relative source from command binding and it works now.